# How to deploy on AWS a Rails webpack_dev_server Docker service?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, amazon-web-services, docker, webpack-dev-server

I have a simple Rails/React app that works with Docker with 3 services:

```
'database' for postgres
'web' for Rails 
'webpack_dev_server' for react
```

In AWS I've created:

```
* built a custom image for nginx,
* set s3 to hold ecs configs.
* a production cluster, 
* private repositories for the 'web' and nginx, tagged both images and pushed to the repositories
* create 4 ec2 instances, 2 for the web and 2 for react
```

Now I'm ready to create task definitions but I'm not sure how to handle webpack_dev_server (React).

Can we build the image with the same dockerfile as the the web?
For the task definition, should it look like the web as well?

Here's the docker-compose.yml file that works.

```
version: '3'

services:

  web:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/app
      - gem_cache:/gems
    env_file:
      - .env/development/database
      - .env/development/web
    environment:
      - WEBPACKER_DEV_SERVER_HOST=webpack_dev_server
      - DOCKERIZED=true

  webpack_dev_server:
    build: .
    command: ./bin/webpack-dev-server
    ports:
      - 3035:3035
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/app
      - gem_cache:/gems
    env_file:
      - .env/development/web
      - .env/development/database
    environment: 
      - WEBPACK_DEV_SERVER=0.0.0.0

  database:
    image: postgres
    env_file:
      - .env/development/database
    volumes:
      - db_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data

volumes:
  db_data:
  gem_cache:
```

Comment: Why deploy a dev-server setup to EC2; why not build your browser application into static files and serve that?  Similarly with your Rails application, you should be able to set it up to just run what's in a Docker image and not need to separately copy your application code.  In an AWS context ECR can be a convenient place to store your images (though the resulting image names become rather long-winded).

Comment: Sorry David, but I don't understand.

React is going to work as just assets?
Don't we need a separate server for the frontend?

the docker-compose file above is very similar to the docs for webpacker and the book "Docker for Rails developers".

Isn't the webpack-dev-server just a different server running on a different port? 

My nodejs friends use two repos when building react apps. They deploy one server for the frontend and one for the backend.

Thanks

Comment: A React application will work fine as "just assets".  Run Webpack wherever it's convenient; that will generally produce something like a `dist` directory with HTML and packaged Javascript files.  Any plain Web server (including S3 public bucket access, or an nginx reverse proxy) can serve these files.